# как стилизовать балун кластера и балун метки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Создаю общий макет балуна для кластера и метки,но не работает,к кластеру применяется к метке нет

```
 <script>   
 MyBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div class="popover-bg">' +
    '<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>' +
    '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
    '<div class="popover-inner">' +
    '$[[options.contentLayout observeSize minWidth=315 maxWidth=auto ]]' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
    }
........
), 
    var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
        clusterDisableClickZoom: false,
        clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
        clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
        clusterBalloonMaxHeight: 200,
        clusterBalloonItemContentLayout: customItemContentLayout,
        clusterBalloonWidth: 315,            
        hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
        clusterBalloonLayout: MyBalloonLayout
    });

    points = [
    [55.831903,37.411961], [55.763338,37.565466], [55.763338,37.565466], [55.744522,37.616378], [55.780898,37.642889]     ]
    var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(points, {
        balloonLayout: MyBalloonLayout,
        balloonContentBody: "тело метки",
    }); 

    placemarks.push(placemark);
    clusterer.add(placemarks);
    whereMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор метки вторым параметром принимает данные, а третьим опции. Вы задаете опцию через данные - поэтому не работает.
Пример корректно заданной опции для макета балуна можно посмотреть тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout